# How to execute swift combine request if previous request unauthorised

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

My starting point is a method like this `foo()` example here. I'm using `retries: 1`.

```swift
    func foo() {

        // create url ...

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(for: url, httpMethod: "POST", resource: nil, token: accessToken)
        let combineRequest = CombineRequest(auth: auth)
        combineRequest.runWithResponseStatus(urlRequest, checkStatusCode: 201, retries: 1)
            .sink { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.toasts.insert(ToastText(type: .error, text: Text("\(error.localizedDescription)")), at: 0)
                    self.clearToasts()
                }
            } receiveValue: { _ in
                // successful
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

So it's a `POST` combine request (`runWithResponseStatus()`). When I get a `401 - unauthorized`, I would like to execute another combine request (`refresh()`).

1. If `refresh()` is successful, it should execute `auth.setAccessToken(to: newAccessToken.token)` and retry it's previously called (`runWithResponseStatus()`) method one more time.
2. Right now, on `.failure` I'm doing a `print("\(error.localizedDescription)")` but I would like to return that error up in the chain so it ends up in the `foo()` method, where I can put it into the toasts array.

Does someone know how to achieve these two points and also, if possible, utilise the power of combine and just make it cleaner?

```swift
struct CombineRequest {
    
    var auth: Auth
    var jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(dateFormatter: .isoDateFormatter)

    func runWithResponseStatus(_ request: URLRequest, checkStatusCode statusCode: Int = 200, queue: DispatchQueue = .main, retries: Int = 0) -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), Error> {
        
        var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .retry(retries)
        .tryMap { output in
            if let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode != statusCode {
                switch response.statusCode {
                case 401:
                    try refresh(decodingType: AccessData.self)
                        .sink { completion in
                            switch completion {
                            case .finished:
                                break
                            case .failure(let error):
                                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        } receiveValue: { newAccessToken in
                            auth.setAccessToken(to: newAccessToken.token)
                        }
                        .store(in: &cancellable)
                case 400:
                    throw ResourceError.internalServerError("General.error.general")
                default:
                    throw ResourceError.httpStatus(response.statusCode)
                }
            }
            return output
        }
        .receive(on: queue)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }


    private func refresh<DecodingType>(checkStatusCode statusCode: Int = 200, queue: DispatchQueue = .main, decodingType: DecodingType.Type) throws -> AnyPublisher<DecodingType, Error> where DecodingType: Decodable {
        
        // prepare all properties ...
        
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: refreshRequest)
            .tryMap { output in
                if let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode != statusCode {
                    switch response.statusCode {
                    case 401:
                        auth.loggedOut()
                    case 400:
                        throw ResourceError.internalServerError("General.error.general")
                    default:
                        auth.loggedOut()
                        throw ResourceError.httpStatus(response.statusCode)
                    }
                }
                return output.data
            }
            .decode(type: DecodingType.self, decoder: jsonDecoder)
            .receive(on: queue)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I am stuck with a similar problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076317/refresh-token-mechanism-with-combine-framework-ios

Comment: @Rocky unfortunately not. Mh I see, It's actually the same problem we want to solve. Execute a request, if unauthorised, refresh token and try the previous request again.

Answer (score 0):

You can `catch` or `replaceError` i believe. Try reading this: https://www.donnywals.com/catch-vs-replaceerror-in-combine/